# How to get text from form and insert it into Database - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am inserting a reduced trip price for my listing. In my form, I display all the trips for that listing. I don't know how to insert the already existing Trip name into the database though. I will show you what i mean.
( I'm not editing a trip, I'am creating a Promotional Listing, so the trip name and reduced price will go into a diffrent table )

I need to insert the "Trip" name on the left

[image: Muy Trips]

This is how I have the form laid out:

```html
 <form class="form" method="post" action="{{ route('user.promotion-store') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Trip</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Reduced Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach( $listings->trips as $trip )
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ $trip->name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${{ $trip->cost }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('reduced_trip_price') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label>Your Reduced Price</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reduced_trip_price" id="reduced_trip_price" placeholder="Optional...">
                                        @if($errors->has('reduced_trip_price'))
                                            <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('reduced_trip_price') }}</span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
   
   </form>
```

And this is how I insert it:

```
public function store(ReducedTripRequest $request) {

        $reducedTrips = ReducedTrips($request->all());
        $reducedTrips->save();

        return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `Trip name` within the form in a hidden input field this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="trip_name" value="{{ $trip->name }}">
```

Then on the server side you can get the `trip_name` and `reduced_trip_price` to do whatever with them as you want.

To insert in a table for example:

```
<?php
NewTable::create([
    'trip_name' => $request->input('trip_name'),
    'reduced_trip_price' => $request->input('reduced_trip_price'),
]);
```

Comment: Yes thats perfect!